# Persist data between page reload in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, apollo-client

I am fetching data from a graphql API, and after fetching the data once, I want it to persist on page reloads, and it should only make a new API call when the query changes. I'm using `@apollo/client` to fetch the data from an API.

My code:

```js
import { useQuery } from "@apollo/client";
import { useSearchParams } from "react-router-dom";

const Component = () => {
  const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(queryGql, {
    variables: queryVariables,
  });

  if (loading) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>;
  }

  if (error) {
    return <div>Error: {error.message}</div>;
  }
  const results = data?.data || [];

  return (
      <div>
        {results.map((result) => (
          <Card name={result.name} key={result.id} />
        ))}
      </div>
  );
};

export default Component;
```

index.js

```js
import { ApolloClient, InMemoryCache, ApolloProvider } from "@apollo/client";

const client = new ApolloClient({
  uri: process.env.BASE_URL,
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
});

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <ApolloProvider client={client}>
      <RouterProvider router={router} />
    </ApolloProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Almost all of this answer comes from [queries#setting-a-fetch-policy](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/queries#setting-a-fetch-policy)

In @apollo/client, You can specify a different fetch policy for a given query. To do so, include the `fetchPolicy` option in your call to `useQuery`:

```
const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(queryGql, {
  fetchPolicy: 'cache-first', // first executes the query against the cache.
});
```

> Apollo Client first executes the query against the cache. If all requested data is present in the cache, that data is returned. Otherwise, Apollo Client executes the query against your GraphQL server and returns that data after caching it.
>
> Prioritizes minimizing the number of network requests sent by your application.

@apollo/client supports the following configurations:

- cache-first
- cache-only
- cache-and-network
- network-only
- no-cache
- standby

In my opinion, you should choose `cache-first`, and it's the default fetch policy.

Answer (score -1):

you can use Redux to do this.

https://redux.js.org/

And use Redux persist for persist the data, even when the page is reloaded

https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist

And then, you can make a condition in your code, to avoid rerunning the query if you already have the data.